# WP7 - Cancelling ContextMenu click event propagation

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, event-handling

I'm having a problem when the Silverlight toolkit's `ContextMenu` is clicked while it is over a `UIElement` that has registered a Tap event `GestureListener`. The context menu click propagates to the underlying element and fires its tap event.

For instance, say I have a `ListBox` and each `ListBoxItem` within it has registered both a `ContextMenu` and a Tap `GestureListener`. Assume that clicking context menu item2 is supposed to take you to Page1.xaml, while tapping on any of ListBox items themselves is supposed to take you to Page2.xaml.

If I open the context menu on item1 in the ListBox, then context menu item2 is on top of ListBox item2. When I click on context menu item2 I get weird behavior where the app navigates to Page1.xaml and then immediately to Page2.xaml because the click event also triggered the Tap gesture for `ListBox` item2.

I've verified in the debugger that it is always the context menu that receives the click event first. How do I cancel the context menu item click's routed event propagation so it doesn't reach ListBox item2?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get around the problem by doing the following:

- In the context menu's `Opened` handler set `LayoutRoot.IsHitTestVisible` (`LayoutRoot` is the default name for the root `UIElement`) to `false`
- In the context menu's `Closed` handler set `LayoutRoot.IsHitTestVisible` back to `true`

Comment: Preplexingly, this only appears to work on some of the pages I try to use it on. I have not tracked down the differences yet. Did you by any chance find a better solution for this issue?

Comment: @Sander No I haven't, I'm still using this technique. It'd be interesting if you could isolate the case where this doesn't work and post a question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a rectangle with a transparent background (important) over the effected area/page when showing the context menu.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I'm not really sure how to accomplish this. How can I overlay a rectangle over the whole page?

Comment: Just place it last in your xaml and it's z-ordering should make it on top.. if you give the background a colour temporarily, then you should be able to verify this visually.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue, but I am using the `ManipulationCompleted` event as a "tap" detector as the object the ContentMenu applies to is a custom control.

`LayoutRoot.IsHitTestVisible` didn't work for me, perhaps because it does not apply to Manipulation events.  However, it set me on the right path.  I just implemented my own simple equivalent of it - I created a boolean variable `bCancelManipulation` in the page's scope.

- In the ContentMenu's `Opened` event set it to True.
- In the ContentMenu's `Closed` event set it to False.
- In the `ManipulationCompleted` function, the first thing I do is check
  `if(bCancelManipulation==true) { return; }`

It's kind of a hack, but it works great and is quite simple to code - it can easily be adapted to a Tap event too.