# Extra tap in the Window Phone 7 ListPicker Control

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I am using a ListPicker in a Wp7 app.  The page that contains the listPicker control also contains a LongListSelector.  Each Element of the LongListSelector has a Click Gesture handler.

When I click the ListPicker in appropriately enters the full screen "Full Mode."  I click on a selection and the full mode appropriately closes.  Then another tap is registered on the parent page of the ListPicker, directly under the spot where I clicked the Full Mode window to make the solution.  I can activate both the index view or the elements of the LongListSelector.

It appears that the ListPicker is failing to mark the tap event as handled, and it is bubblling up.  Has anyone else noticed this behavior?  Any workarrounds?

Comment: Hi John, I had a similar problem with the `ContextMenu` where clicking on it would propagate the click to elements lying underneath (that had a `Tap` gesture registered). I've stated the workaround here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697107/wp7-cancelling-contextmenu-click-event-propagation/4697652#4697652

I'm not sure how you can apply that to a `ListPicker` though, cause I couldn't find `Opened` and `Closed` events.

Comment: Are you setting `e.Handled = true` in the `Click` gesture handler for your `LongListSelector` items?

Comment: Which version fo the toolkit are you using? Can you provide a sample that recreates this please. My attempts to recreate your scenario have failed to create what you're describing above.

Comment: I did try the e.handled = true and this did not resolve the problem. I was using the Fall 2010 build of the toolkit.

Comment: I do not have a quick sample.  I ended up "building my own" using a button that navigates to a subpage in order to get the behavior I needed.  It looks, from answers below, like at least one person has replicated this with the Feb 2011 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sort of work around which worked for me when I had the same problem:

You need to add a FullHeaderItemTemplate with a handle to load and unload events.

```
<toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <Grid Margin="12,15,12,15">
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}"
                  Loaded="TextBlockLoaded"
                  Unloaded="TextBlockUnloaded"
                  Style="{Binding PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />
     </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
```

for the events, you need to have the following:

```
    private void TextBlockLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LayoutRoot.IsHitTestVisible = false;
    }

    private void TextBlockUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LayoutRoot.IsHitTestVisible = true;
    }
```